# Breaking a monolithic java app

Tags: java, git, maven, dependency-management

I am in the process of breaking a monolithic Java application into smaller modules, so we can better tests, etc. I see most of the benefits but also some issues:

- The core application will have its own lifecycle.
- Each module will have its own lifecycle.

My interrogations are around the **process**: I have done it in the past, but need to refresh my processes.

What are good practices or issues are you following?

For this project, we use Maven and git.

Edit:
I realize it is a very broad question, I simplified.

Comment: Way too broad. Way too many questionS in your text.

Comment: @GhostCat: I know, I edited a bit, but it is still broad Gerold did a good reply thus.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This question is a bit broad, but I'm going to give it a try nevertheless.

There are two good online books at Sonatype:

- [Maven: The Complete Reference](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book/reference/index.html)
- [Maven by Example](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/index.html)

And, of course, [the Maven site](https://maven.apache.org/index.html) itself.

Artifact names are derived from `<artifactId>` and `<version>`. See [Apache Maven JAR Plugin / Usage](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/usage.html), [Guide to naming conventions on groupId, artifactId and version](https://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-naming-conventions.html) and also [Understanding Maven Version Numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN8855). See [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Corg.apache) for examples how it is done by others. A good approach from my POV is to include the last part(s) of the `<groupId>` in the `<artifactId>` like [Apache Commons](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3Aorg.apache.commons) does it. Such you can easily identify an artifact just by its name.

*"keep -SNAPSHOT in your poms?"*

- As a consumer of `<dependencies>` it depends whether you decide to rely just on fixed released versions, the behaviour of which doesn't change while you use them. Or whether you need the latest functionality implemented in `-SNAPSHOT`s of the `<dependencies>` you use.
- For a project's `<version>` itself you keep `-SNAPSHOT` until you prepare a release. When releasing you change to a release version for the short period of the release process. After it you immediately change to a higher `-SNAPSHOT` version.

See the examples at the [Maven Release Plugin](https://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/index.html) for the tasks to be done at the end of a release cycle.

A `<dependencyManagement>` section in your top parent POM makes sense.

Maven and Git are excellent choices. ;)